Error in Java : incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for PriorityQueue<>
class Solution {
    class City{
        int city;
        long time;
        City(int c, long t){
            city = c;
            time = t;
        }
    }
    public int countPaths(int n, int[][] roads) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<City>> graph = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            graph.add(new ArrayList<>());
        for(int[] road : roads){
            graph.get(road[0]).add(new City(road[1], road[2]));
            graph.get(road[1]).add(new City(road[0], road[2]));
        }
        // for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        //     System.out.print(i+"-");
        //     for(City c : graph.get(i))
        //         System.out.print("("+c.city+","+c.time+")");
        //     System.out.println();
        // }

        PriorityQueue<City> pq= new PriorityQueue<>((a,b) -> (a.time - b.time));
        long[] times = new long[n];
        int[] ways = new int[n];
        Arrays.fill(times, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        times[0] = 0;
        ways[0] = 1;
        pq.add(new City(0, 0));
        int mod = (int) (1e9 + 7);

        while(!pq.isEmpty()){
            City c = pq.remove();
            for(City near : graph.get(c.city)){
                long cost = c.time + near.time;
                if(cost < times[near.city]){
                    times[near.city] = cost;
                    ways[near.city] = ways[c.city];
                    pq.add(new City(near.city, times[near.city]));
                }
                else if(cost == times[near.city])
                    ways[near.city] = (ways[near.city] +  ways[c.city]) % mod;
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ways));
        return ways[n-1] % mod;
    }
}

This is the error:
Line 25: error: incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for PriorityQueue<>
        PriorityQueue<City> pq= new PriorityQueue<>((a,b) -> (a.time - b.time));
                                                 ^
    reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) E
      (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
        possible lossy conversion from long to int)
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class PriorityQueue

I tried giving initial capacity but it did not work same error. Can anyone tell me why this error occur and how to resolve it.This error occured when I change the datatype of time in class City from int to long.
The question is from 1976 Leetcode question Number of ways to arrive at destination.

Subtraction is not the same as comparison. Supplying (a-b) as a substitute for comparison will cause you trouble.


Bad return type in lambda expression: long cannot be converted to int

The compare method expects to return an int, but you are performing arithmetic with two long values. It will throw an error, because there is a lossy conversion (i.e. largest long value cannot fit inside an int, and if casted to int will lose information). In the occasion that the subtraction of the two compared values results in a long value (does not fit in an int) but is casted to an int, this loss of information will result in an arithmetic overflow (going past Integer.MAX_VALUE and starting again from Integer.MIN_VALUE)
As mentioned by @Asmir the following are best practices (These functions compare long values, but obey the compareTo contract by returning ints -1, 0, 1 depending on if this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object)
Comparator.comparingLong(a->a.time)
(a, b) -> Long.compare(a.time, b.time) 

See also the JLS on Narrowing Primitive Conversions:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html

Just out of curiosity: Why cast long to int? Wouldn't a simple new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> Long.compare(a.time, b.time)) or something like new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingLong(a -> a.time)) solve the issue?

@Asmir that would probably be best. I didnt think of that because my first thought is to cast to int when the return requires an int, but my IDE suggested the Math.toIntExact(), so I included both.

This answer would be much improved by just ditching the first 2 snippets. Feel free to explain why the error occurs, then do mention overflow throws a wrench in the works when attempting to use - as an ersatz comparator impl. But don't show "These are dumb ways to do it". Just show the right way.
